# How to properly use fold left in a scala function

Tags: scala

I've a problem with this part of code in scala

```
object Test12 {
  def times(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
    val sortedChars = chars.sorted
    sortedChars.foldLeft (List[(Char, Int)]()) ((l, e) =>
        if(l.head._1 == e){
            (e, l.head._2 + 1) :: l.tail
        } else {
            (e, 1) :: l
        } )
  }

  val s = List('a', 'b')

  val c = times s
}
```

The last line give an error :

> Missing arguments for method times; follow this method with `_' if you
>   want to treat it as a partially applied function

But I don't see why, because I've given 2 arguments to the last function - foldLeft.

Thanks in advance for help!

The idea of code is to count how much time each character is present in a given list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of times is fine, but you need to use parenthesis when calling it, i.e. :

```
val c = times(s)
```

But it won't work because you use l.head without checking if l is Nil, and an empty list does not have a head. You can e.g. check with match for that:

```
def times(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
  val sortedChars = chars.sorted
  sortedChars.foldLeft (List[(Char, Int)]()) ((a,b) => (a,b) match {
    case (Nil, e) => (e, 1) :: Nil
    case ((e, count) :: l, f) => 
        if (e == f) (e, count + 1) :: l
        else (f, 1) :: (e, count) :: l
  })
}
```

Although an easier way is to use the higher level collection functions:

```
def times(chars: List[Char]) = chars.groupBy(c=>c).map(x=>(x._1,x._2.length)).toList
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val c = times s
```

You can't call method without brackets like this. Try `times(s)` or `this times s`.